# How event Called In Asp.net

Tags: asp.net

Is There any article that explain event call in asp.net?

Comment: What event? What context? We need more details if you want real answer..

Comment: @Shadow Wizard : any event! DropDownlist SelectedIndexChange. Button Click and ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ASP.NET event model is documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y3bwdsh3.aspx).

Comment: a question : is there any situation that a viewstate lost in postback? i face a problem when a dropdownlist selectedindexchange and postback happend and my textbox value lost! not always. Rarely.

Comment: @Raika, assuming `EnableViewState` is `true` on the `TextBox` and on the page, nothing should be lost. Maybe you're resetting the text box value somewhere during the page lifecycle, or maybe you're clearing it on the client side before the postback occurs. I'd suggest you ask that in another question, along with all the necessary information: maybe others will have a better explanation.